# What is the variable 'i' mean after the array declaration

Tags: java, arrays

I came across a Java program to merge sort some numbers. Here is a snippet of the code which I am a bit confused with.

```
int n;
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
n=in.nextInt();
int A []=new int[n],i;
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
```

In the above code the line `int A []=new int[n],i;`What does this `i` stand for. Is it a declaration of an int variable called `i`? Or does it have another meaning. Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Pick a language 1st please. C++ isn't Java.

Comment: Is this Java or C++?

Comment: Looks somewhat golfed. It's a shortening of `int[] A = new int[n];` and `int i;`

Comment: Same concept as int j=5, i;

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't have thought it compiles.

Comment: @Mureinik if you read the first sentence you would know that I have mentioned it as a java program.

Comment: and why did you tag it with c++ after you wrote that sentence?

Comment: Thought people who know about C++ may know Java as well!

Comment: That's not how tags work at Stack Overflow. Only use tags that are directly related to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is declaration of `int` type variable. But it is more better to declare that `int i` in `for` like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

Also more whitespaces increase code readability

You can declare variables like this
`TYPE var1, var2, var3, ..., varN;`

And all variables will have same type

Comment: It's bad practice to declare multiple variables in the same declaration, *especially* when mixing array and scalar types.

Comment: @LewBloch The first point seems highly subjective. Not that I disagree, personally.

Comment: @shmosel  I agree with you. +1

Comment: My comment about "practice" is based on reading of the pundits more than my personal taste. While it may seem "highly" subjective, there is wide industry agreement, and the measure itself is objective. The example here itself illustrates that the many-per-line approach reduces readability, and this is measurable. So I claim that the principle is "highly" objective.